# Syntax error with for loop in Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a method in Java to find a center of mass of a polygon. I got all the math needed and started coding, but I am getting an error and I don't know how to fix it. The error is shown on the line where the for cycle is initialised (`for (i = 0, i < n, i++)`) Here is my code:

```
public static double[] com (double [] x, double [] y, int n)
{
    x [n] = x [0];
    y [n] = y [0];
    double a = 0;
    double xc = 0;
    double yc = 0;
    int i; 
    for (i = 0, i < n, i++)
    {
        a = a + Math.abs(x[i] * y [i + 1] - x [i + 1] * y [i]);
        xc = xc + (x[i] + x [i + 1]) * (x [i] * y [i + 1]) - (x [i + 1] * y [i]);
        yc = yc + (y [i] + y [ i + 1]) * (x [i] * y [i + 1]) - (x [i + 1] * y[i]);
     }
    a = a / 2;
    xc = xc / (6 * a);
    yc = yc / (6 * a);
    System.out.println ("Xc = " + xc + " Yc = " + yc);
    return new double [] {xc,yc};
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: voted to close because the problem is caused by a simple typographical error

Comment: Indent your code, please. For the sake of *everybody* reading it (including *you*).

Comment: Your subject line is completely misleading.  You don't have an algorithm problem, you have a plain and simple syntax error.

Comment: are you not using an IDE ?

Comment: that is some impossible-to-read code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use semicolons between the three clauses in the `for` statement, not commas.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct syntax.
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

use semicolons instead of commas.